# cannot access input field in protractor tests

Tags: angularjs, protractor

I am new to Angularjs/Protractor and having difficulty accessing an input tag in my tests. Running the app in the browser sets the input fields to the init values. But I can't seem to grab them or write to these fields in my tests. The output result of protractor is:

```
$protractor conf.js 
>[18:07:56] I/hosted - Using the selenium server at http://localhost:4444/wd/hub
>[18:07:56] I/launcher - Running 1 instances of WebDriver
>Started 
>F
>Failures:
>1) When loading component loginComp the email/password get init values
>  Message:
>    Expected '' to be 'abc@example.com'.
>Stack:
>  Error: Failed expectation 
>   ....stack trace
>1 spec, 1 failure
>Finished in 1.101 seconds
>[18:07:58] I/launcher - 0 instance(s) of WebDriver still running
>[18:07:58] I/launcher - chrome #01 failed 1 test(s)
>[18:07:58] I/launcher - overall: 1 failed spec(s)
>[18:07:58] E/launcher - Process exited with error code 1
```

Here is the index.html:

```
index.html:
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>Test directives</title>
</head>
<body ng-app="docsapp">
  <div> Here is the test</div>
   <div>
    <login-comp></login-comp>
   </div>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.5.6/angular.js">  </script>
  <script src="app/app.module.js"></script>
  <script src="app/login-comp/login-comp.module.js"></script>
  <script src="app/login-comp/login-comp.component.js"></script>
 </body>
</html>
```

Here is the loginComp module:

```
login-comp.module.js:
angular.module('loginComp', [])
```

Here is the loginComp component def:

```
function LoginCompController() {
  var vm = this;
  this.user = {
    email: "admin@example.com",
    password: "password" 
  }
}

angular.module('loginComp')
.component('loginComp', {
  templateUrl: './app/login-comp/login-comp.template.html',
  controller: LoginCompController,
  controllerAs: 'vm'
});
```

Here is the loginComp template:

```
login-comp.template.html:
<input type="email" ng-model="vm.user.email"/>
<hr>
<input type="password" ng-model="vm.user.password"/>
```

Here is the test file:

```
login-comp.component.spec.js:
describe("When loading component loginComp", function() {
  beforeEach(function() {
    browser.get("http://127.0.0.1:8080/");
  });
  it("the email/password get init values", function() {
    var email = element(by.model("vm.user.email"));

    email.sendKeys("abc@example.com").then(function() {
      expect(email.getText()).toBe("abc@example.com");
    });

  });
});
```

I have tried different variations on the test: reading from the email input field, writing to it. I also tried using "user.email" or "email" to access the input field but this gives errors (Failed: No element found using locator: by.model("user.email")).

If anyone has seen this error before on Stackoverflow, please send me the link. I've reviewed many protractor-related issues and none apply to my case.

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is from the [protractor FAQ](https://github.com/angular/protractor/blob/master/docs/faq.md#the-result-of-gettext-from-an-input-element-is-always-empty):

**The result of getText from an input element is always empty**

This is a webdriver quirk. input and textarea elements always have empty getText values. Instead, try:

```
element.getAttribute('value')
```

Comment: Thanks! That worked. There is a tutorial on the PluralSight website on Protractor that uses getText a lot. It worked in the tutorial, so I assumed something else was wrong.